# SQL Server Select Max of a Sum

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

When I run this select

```
SELECT      
     D.Product_ID p_id
    ,D.Green_Sheet_ID gs_id
    ,SUM (P.prepress_amt) amt

   FROM  GS_Prepress AS P INNER JOIN
                      GS_Data AS D ON P.green_sheet_id = D.Green_Sheet_ID

   WHERE 
    Product_ID ='194456'  
   GROUP BY D.Product_ID, D.Green_Sheet_ID
```

I get this...

```
|p_id   | gs_id |amt      |
|-------|-------|---------|
|194456 | 5721  |33524.00 |
|194456 | 7484  |47524.00 |
```

I only want to select the row with the max(gs_is), so I only get this result?

```
|p_id   | gs_id |amt      |
|-------|-------|---------|
|194456 | 7484  |47524.00 |
```

Comment: Add TOP(1) and ORDER BY properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use this query to ever pull more than one Product_ID then this will only return the relevant results. If your end result is only to have one item returned then use Marcin's answer.

```
SELECT D.Product_ID p_id
, D.Green_Sheet_ID gs_id
,SUM (P.prepress_amt) amt
FROM  GS_Prepress AS P 
   INNER JOIN GS_Data AS D ON P.green_sheet_id = D.Green_Sheet_ID
   INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(Green_Sheet_ID) AS gs_ID
               FROM GS_Date
               GROUP BY Product_ID) G ON G.Gs_ID = D.Green_Sheet_ID

WHERE Product_ID ='194456'  
GROUP BY D.Product_ID, D.Green_Sheet_ID
```

Answer (score 5):

Order the results and take `TOP(1)`:

```
SELECT TOP(1)
    D.Product_ID p_id,
    D.Green_Sheet_ID gs_id,
    SUM (P.prepress_amt) amt
FROM
    GS_Prepress AS P
INNER JOIN
    GS_Data AS D ON P.green_sheet_id = D.Green_Sheet_ID
WHERE 
    Product_ID ='194456'  
GROUP BY
    D.Product_ID, D.Green_Sheet_ID
ORDER BY
    gs_id DESC
```

Comment: I think it should be `order by gs_id desc`

Comment: @Kaf - The title says max of a sum though.

Comment: Right, wrong order column... But the title is *Max of sum*... Thanks!

Comment: @MartinSmith: not a big issue `:D`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say that I need to be able to comment out my product_ID so I will have many product_id's with multiple D.Green_Sheet_ID's and I just need the max D.Green_Sheet_ID row.